# How to remove all lines from an image? (horizontal, vertical, diagonal)

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, imagemagick

I need to remove the lines in an image, which is a table eventually. I have found a way to remove the horizontal and vertical lines:

```
convert 1.jpg -type Grayscale -negate -define morphology:compose=darken -morphology Thinning 'Rectangle:1x80+0+0<' -negate out.jpg
```

The following image:

[image]

Was converted to the following one:

[image]

As one can see the diagonal line is still there. I tried to rotate the image for 45 degrees and then try to remove it, but was also unsuccessful. How it can be done? Any suggestions are appreciated. I opted for imagemagick, but any other options are welcome

Comment: I guess you could use Hough transform to find the line, then draw the line in white on a black background and composite onto original with the **Lighten** mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You can try using [`cv2.HoughLinesP()`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html) to detect the diagonal line then use a mask to fill in the contour

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
canny = cv2.Canny(gray,100,200)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(canny, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
minLineLength = 10
maxLineGap = 350
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(close,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        cv2.line(mask,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,255,255),3)

mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imwrite('image.png', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Good answer. And after finding the lines, you might look into inpainting to fill them in rather than just filling them white: https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_photo/py_inpainting/py_inpainting.html

Comment: But this doesn't work for me. The mask just removes a rectangular patch from it. Did anyone actually run and test the code?

Answer (score 4):

Here is another approach. I use Imagemagick, since I am not proficient with OpenCV. Basically, I binarize the image. Then do connected components processing to isolate the largest contiguous black region, which will be the black lines you want to exclude. Then use that as a mask to fill in white over the lines. This is Unix syntax with Imagemagick.

Note that some text characters will be lost, if they touch the black lines.

**Input:**

[image]

**Get the id number of the largest black region:**

```
id=`convert Arkey.jpg -threshold 50% -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 4 null: |\
grep "gray(0)" | head -n 1 | sed -n 's/^ *\(.*\):.*$/\1/p'`
```

**Isolate the black lines and dilate them**

```
convert Arkey.jpg -threshold 50% -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:keep=$id \
-connected-components 4 \
-alpha extract \
-morphology dilate octagon:2 \
mask.png
```

[image]

**Fill white over the lines in the image using the mask for control:**

```
convert Arkey.jpg \( -clone 0 -fill white -colorize 100 \) mask.png -compose over -composite result.png
```

[image]

See -connected-components at https://imagemagick.org/script/connected-components.php for details how it works.